# Dropbox Python API: files_search TypeError: Missing argument

Tags: python, typeerror, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've included the two arguments needed stated in the documentation, but I get an error saying that I'm missing a positional argument.

Code:
`db_results = dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_search(db_path, db_query)`

Error:
`TypeError: files_search() is missing one positional argument: 'query'`

[Documentation: files_search()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvnul.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create an instance of a `Dropbox` client](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox) with an access and/or refresh token, and use that client to perform the call.

There's a [Getting Started guide here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/getting-started#writing%20a%20script), as well as [an example here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/back-up-and-restore/backup-and-restore-example.py#L79), that may be helpful.

Also, you should use [`files_search_v2`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_search_v2) and [`files_search_continue_v2`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_search_continue_v2) instead of `files_search` now.